# asp .net jquery changing table row color after confrim dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I've already done changing color on click,  but the problem is that, every time I refres the page, colors dissapear. Does anybody know ho to fix it?

And also I would like have some confirm dialog saying something like "are you sure about changing color?"

Here is my code, dialog doesnt work.

```
<script>
    function changeMe(el) {
        $("somet").dialog({
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                Ok: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
        el.style.backgroundColor = "#05AA05";
        el.style.color = "#000000";
    }
</script>
```

and the table (I fill it with for each cycle, byt it's not relevant I think)

```
        {
            <tr onclick="changeMe(this);">
                <td>@Ajax.ActionLink(r.Jmeno.ToString(), "Detail", new { id = r.Jmeno }, new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "modalContent", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, OnBegin = "openModalWindow" }), @r.Prijmeni</td>
                <td>@r.Rez_kolobezky.Reg_cislo</td>
                <td>@r.Datum_od</td>
                <td>@r.Datum_do</td>
            </tr>
        }
```

So please could anyone help me? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you refresh the page you will reload the original styles. You need some way to save the color change status and recall it again after a page load.

You could use browser cookies to do this.

Store the color, backgroundColor and row index in a cookie, then read the cookie on each page load and set the values if they exist.